# What does the &^ operator do?

Tags: go, bit-manipulation

According to the [specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec) this operator is called bit clear:

```
&^   bit clear (AND NOT)    integers
```

I've never heard of such an operator before, and I'm wondering why is it useful.

It seems to take the left operand and disables all the bits that are turned on in the right operand. Is there any formal description of the operator?
One more thing I noticed is that it's not commutative.
Pseudocode in comarison with `^`:

```
11110 &^ 100 //11010
11110  ^ 100 //11010

11110 &^ 0 //11110
11110  ^ 0 //11110

11110 &^ 11110 //0
11110  ^ 11110 //0

11110 &^ 111 //11000
11110  ^ 111 //11001

111 &^ 11110 //1
111  ^ 11110 //11001
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Supposing this question should not be closed (I don't know), then your comment is probably all that can be said so you should make it an answer, don't you think ?

Comment: @dystroy: And thus it is so.

Comment: 255 & 128 = 128,  255 &^ 128 = 123 at a guess

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the symbol (a concatenation of `&` and `^`), the name "and not" (and also the term "bit clear" which sounds like the opposite of "bit set"), it seems evident that `A &^ B` is doing `A & ^B` (where `^` is the bitwise inverse).

This is backed up by examining the operator's truth table:

```
fmt.Println(0 &^ 0);    // 0
fmt.Println(0 &^ 1);    // 0
fmt.Println(1 &^ 0);    // 1
fmt.Println(1 &^ 1);    // 0
```

(See http://ideone.com/s4Pfe9.)

Comment: `11110 &^ 111 //11000`. But `~111` is `000`, and `11110 & 000` is `000`.

Comment: @shock_one: Remember that `111` is actually `00...00111`.

Comment: `~x` is `^x` in go, which makes `&^` more consistent than your answer suggests.

Comment: @Anonymous: That being the case, why does this operator exist?  Why couldn't the language just parse it as `A & ^B`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth (^1) is an untyped int constant equal to -2, so `uint(11) & (^1)` isn't a valid expression because -2 isn't a valid unsigned int (and there's no implicit type conversion ever in go). In other words, it's a way of making bit clear play nicely with constants.